# I am trying to validate mobile with javaScript but it not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a mobile and I want to check if the mobile number is less then 10 or greater then 13 then I want to show the message

My code:

```
<input name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="+91" class="form-control tboxs" type="text" style="font-family: 'JameelKhushkhatLRegular'">

<button style="width: 100%" type="button"  id="submit" value="submit" class="btn-theme-colored btn">SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send">
```

```
        <script>
            $('#submit').click(function(){
       if($('#first_name').val() == '' ){
          alert('Name can not be left blank and atleast 4 char long');
          return false;
        }else if(!$("input[name='redio_gender']:checked").val()){
          alert('Please Select Gender');
          return false;   
        }else if($('#multiple').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select Age');
          return false;
        }else if($('#profession').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select your Profession');
          return false;
        }else if($('#taluka').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select Taluka');
          return false;
        }else if($('#village').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Enter village');
          return false;  
        }else if($('#interest').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select Area of Interest');
          return false;   
        }else if($('#masjid').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Enter Nearest Masjid');
          return false; 
        }else if($('#mobile').val( ) == '' || parseInt($('#mobile').val() < 10 )  ||  parseInt($('#mobile').val() > 13)) {
          alert('Please Enter Valid Mobile Number');
          return false;  
        }else{  
          $.ajax({
              --
              --
              });
       }
 });
        </script>
```

In the above code, I validate my code with javascript.

Comment: Your code starts with `}else if` without any previous `if` statement and lacks a closing `}`. Please fix that first and update your code.

Comment: I understand why it is not working. your provided js is wrong on many levels. btw, you may as well just use the pattern attribute on input.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß I Upload the code in my question.

Comment: Your application of parseInt is wrong. If you want to convert a string to a number you don't ```parseInt(x < 10)``` but ```parseInt(x) < 10```. But anyway you don't want to convert a mobile number to an int. You just want to check its length.

Comment: Currently you are parsing the mobile number as integer and just saying "is this 10 characters long number less than 10?" obviously it is not. You should check the length of the mobile number instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var mob = '03311111111';

if( mob.length < 10 || mob.length > 13){
    // show error message
}
```

Comment: If the mobile number empty then?

Comment: An empty string has length 0 which is satisfied by mob.length < 10. @farhantechno

Comment: if mobile no is empty then modify condition like this

if( (typeof mob == 'undefined' || mob == "" ) && (mob.length < 10 || mob.length > 13 ) ){
    // show error message
}

Answer (score 2):

https://jqueryvalidation.org

```
      $.validator.addMethod(
        'phone',
        function (value, element, requiredValue) {
          var phoneRegexp = /^\+380\d{7,10}$/;
          return phoneRegexp.test(value);
        },
      );

      var validator = $('#form_id').validate({
              debug: true,
              errorClass: 'error-class',
              errorElement: 'div',
              rules: {
                  'phone': {
                      required: true,
                      phone: true,
                      minlength: 10,
                      maxlength: 13
                  }
              },
          }
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
    if(mobile.length < 10 || mobile.length > 13) {
        //mobile length is less than 10 or greater than 13, show error message
    }
});
```

Your final code would be this:

```
 <script>
       $('#submit').click(function(){

       var mobile = $('#mobile').val();

       if($('#first_name').val() == '' ){
          alert('Name can not be left blank and at least 4 char long');
          return false;
        } else if(!$("input[name='redio_gender']:checked").val()){
          alert('Please Select Gender');
          return false;   
        } else if($('#multiple').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select Age');
          return false;
        } else if($('#profession').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select your Profession');
          return false;
        } else if($('#taluka').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select Taluka');
          return false;
        } else if($('#village').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Enter village');
          return false;  
        } else if($('#interest').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Select Area of Interest');
          return false;   
        } else if($('#masjid').val( ) == '') {
          alert('Please Enter Nearest Masjid');
          return false; 
        } else if(mobile.length < 10 || mobile.length > 13) {
          alert('Please Enter Valid Mobile Number');
          return false;  
        } else {  
          $.ajax({
              --
              --
              });
       }
 });
        </script>
```

Or you could use html attributes to do that by using `minlength` and `maxlength` on the text input and you may even want to switch the input type from `text` to `tel`

```
<input name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="+91" class="form-control tboxs" type="tel" style="font-family: 'JameelKhushkhatLRegular'" minlength='10' maxlength='13'>
```